# Count the probability in a cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, probability, markov

Hei, I have a cell array, the second column is the times of 'XX->XX', for example:

```
'AA->AA'    [21]    [4.2084]
'AA->AC'    [15]    [3.0060]
'AA->AG'    [ 9]    [1.8036]
'AA->AT'    [12]    [2.4048]
'AC->CA'    [14]    [2.8056]
'AC->CC'    [16]    [3.2064]
'AC->CG'    [ 5]    [1.0020]
'AC->CT'    [ 3]    [0.6012]
'AG->GA'    [11]    [2.2044]
'AG->GC'    [ 5]    [1.0020]
'AG->GG'    [ 8]    [1.6032]
'AG->GT'    [13]    [2.6052]
'AT->TA'    [10]    [2.0040]
'AT->TC'    [ 8]    [1.6032]
'AT->TG'    [ 2]    [0.4008]
'AT->TT'    [11]    [2.2044]
'CA->AA'    [17]    [3.4068]
'CA->AC'    [ 7]    [1.4028]
'CA->AG'    [ 9]    [1.8036]
'CA->AT'    [11]    [2.2044]
'CC->CA'    [15]    [3.0060]
'CC->CC'    [ 5]    [1.0020]
'CC->CG'    [ 4]    [0.8016]
'CC->CT'    [17]    [3.4068]
'CG->GA'    [ 1]    [0.2004]
'CG->GC'    [ 2]    [0.4008]
'CG->GG'    [ 9]    [1.8036]
'CG->GT'    [ 3]    [0.6012]
'CT->TA'    [ 7]    [1.4028]
'CT->TC'    [ 9]    [1.8036]
'CT->TG'    [ 9]    [1.8036]
'CT->TT'    [ 2]    [0.4008]
'GA->AA'    [10]    [2.0040]
'GA->AC'    [ 4]    [0.8016]
'GA->AG'    [10]    [2.0040]
'GA->AT'    [ 2]    [0.4008]
'GC->CA'    [ 2]    [0.4008]
'GC->CC'    [ 7]    [1.4028]
'GC->CG'    [ 6]    [1.2024]
'GC->CT'    [ 3]    [0.6012]
'GG->GA'    [ 6]    [1.2024]
'GG->GC'    [ 6]    [1.2024]
'GG->GG'    [ 4]    [0.8016]
'GG->GT'    [ 8]    [1.6032]
'GT->TA'    [ 6]    [1.2024]
'GT->TC'    [11]    [2.2044]
'GT->TG'    [ 8]    [1.6032]
'GT->TT'    [ 5]    [1.0020]
'TA->AA'    [ 8]    [1.6032]
'TA->AC'    [13]    [2.6052]
'TA->AG'    [ 9]    [1.8036]
'TA->AT'    [ 6]    [1.2024]
'TC->CA'    [13]    [2.6052]
'TC->CC'    [13]    [2.6052]
'TC->CT'    [ 4]    [0.8016]
'TG->GA'    [ 8]    [1.6032]
'TG->GC'    [ 5]    [1.0020]
'TG->GG'    [ 3]    [0.6012]
'TG->GT'    [ 6]    [1.2024]
'TT->TA'    [13]    [2.6052]
'TT->TC'    [ 2]    [0.4008]
'TT->TG'    [ 3]    [0.6012]
'TT->TT'    [ 5]    [1.0020]
```

Now, I am trying to calculate the probability: P('AA->AA')=TIMES('AA->AA')/SUM('AA->AA','AA->AC','AA->AG','AA->AT'), in other words, P('AA->AA')=TIMES('AA->AA')/SUM('AA->Anyone'). The same with others. I would like to use a loop to do that, but there is a extremal case in

```
'TC->CA'    [13]    [2.6052]
'TC->CC'    [13]    [2.6052]
'TC->CT'    [ 4]    [0.8016]
```

well, it is obviously that the times of 'TC->CG' is 0, which required to be considered also even we already know the probability should be 0. Of course, this extremal case can be happened at any other one like, may be it lack 'TT->TT' sometimes, or 'TC->CT' sometimes.
Anyone get an idea how to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: So the output would be a cell array of probabilities, but with more rows for the cases  like 'TC->CG', which aren't mentioned in the input cell array?

Comment: Yes.it should be that.

Comment: How many cases are missing? Approximately I mean, is it like 10 or more like 100?

Comment: you are giving yourself such a hard time sticking to that string notation `'AC'`, `'TC->CA'` etc. - could you just store these notations in an array and work with its indices? Or more advanced, I assume every letter combination is a gene or a protein or something. This application screams for object orientated programming. Create a `class` proteins and then you can give every protein a name and value and whatever. It is much easier to work with then.

Comment: The simple answer is to code it just like you describe: loop, look for the string, use the second column number if found, otherwise use zero.  Where are you running into trouble?  But @thewaywewalk is right: this storage format will cause you pain.  A common way to represent this sort of data is a "transition matrix", where all the states (16 for you) are listed as rows, for the starting state, and again as columns, for the ending state.  The element at the intersection is the number of occurrences, or the probability.  Populate such a matrix from the cell, then look up the values you want.

Comment: Thanks all your guys, especially Divakar. I tried container.map and with a loop, I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
%%// Get the cell data into data1
data1 = INPUT_DATA;

%%// Get the data from columns separately
col1 = data1(:,1);
tag_data = vertcat(col1{:});

col2 = data1(:,2);
times_data = vertcat(col2{:});

col3 = data1(:,3);
col3_data = vertcat(col3{:});

%%// Get full data for tag, times and column3
char_array = ['A' 'C' 'G' 'T'];
full_tag_data = char_array(combinator(4,3,'p','r'));
full_tag_data = [full_tag_data(:,1:2) repmat('->',[size(full_tag_data,1) 1]) full_tag_data(:,2:3)];

present_rows = ismember(full_tag_data,tag_data,'rows');
full_times_data = double(present_rows);
full_times_data(present_rows) = times_data;

full_col3_data = double(present_rows);
full_col3_data(present_rows) = col3_data;

%%// Get the sum values
full_col3_data_summed = sum(reshape(full_col3_data,4,[]),1);
full_col3_data_summed = reshape(repmat(full_col3_data_summed,[4 1]),[],1);

%%// Store the required values into a cell array out_cell1
out_cell1 = cell(size(present_rows,1),2);
out_cell1(:,1) = cellstr(full_tag_data);
out_cell1(:,2) = num2cell(full_times_data);
out_cell1(:,3) = num2cell(full_col3_data);

%%// The probabilities are added into the cell array as the fourth column
out_cell1(:,4) = num2cell(full_times_data./full_col3_data_summed);
```

**Note:** The above code uses a function `combinator`, which is available [here](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations).